# How to return a string from a method

Tags: c#, string

How can I return a value as text instead of `void`?

Example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = myvoid("foo", true);
    // Error: Cannot implicitly convert type void to string
}

public void myvoid(string key , bool data)
{
    if (data == true)
    {
        string a = key + " = true";
        MessageBox.Show(a); // How can I export this value to labe1.Text?
    }
    else
    {
        string a = key + " = false";
        MessageBox.Show(a); // How can I export this value to labe1.Text?
    }
}
```

How can I assign value `a` from a method that returns void, instead of showing a message box, and apply it to `label1.Text`?

Comment: `== true` == bad

Comment: well, don't return a void, return a string.. !!

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
public string myvoid(string key, bool data)
{
    return key + " = " + data;
}
```

Also, your method shouldn't be called `myvoid` any more since it actually returns a value. Something like `FormatValue` would be better.

Comment: great answer. maybe include the [string.Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565597/c-sharp-how-to-void-to-string#comment15299159_11565650) possibility?

Comment: Do you not need a `.ToString()` on the `data`?

Comment: @lc. the `+` should take care of that

Comment: @lc. You do not when you use `+` to concat strings, the operator overload handles calling `ToString()`.

Comment: @lc.: Nope... but it *will* be capitalized, as per the CLS. http://ideone.com/VoWo1

Comment: actually, it is `mystring` now

Answer (score 5):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = myvoid("foo", true);
}

public string myvoid(string key , bool data)
{
    if (data)       
        return key + " = true";         
    else       
        return  key + " = false"; 
}
```

As [Austin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4068/austin-salonen) mentioned in the comment, this would be more clean

```
public string myvoid(string key , bool data)
{
   return string.Format("{0} = {1}", key, data);
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 3):

Change the return type to string:

```
 public string myvoid(string key, bool data)
 {
    string a = string.Empty;
    if (data == true)
    {
        a = key + " = true";
        MessageBox.Show(a); // How can I export this value to labe1.Text?
    }
    else
    {
        a = key + " = false";
        MessageBox.Show(a); // How can I export this value to labe1.Text?
    }
    return a;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the return type of your method to string.

Like this: `public string myvoid(string key , bool data)`

And then return the string a;

Like this:

```
return a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.80).aspx.

If you really want to use a `void`, you can use the `out` predicate for this.

Comment: Why would you want to use a void when you really want to return a string? `out` + `void` is really just bad style (and I would imagine there's overhead involved too)

Comment: Careful about suggesting the `out` predicate too, you can't use it with properties like `label1.Text`, you would have to create a string, send it into the method, and then set `label1.Text`.

Comment: Also, you can use the out if you want to abstract yourself from the function output definition. It makes sense in some scenarios. Don't see why the downvote on this...

Comment: Quoting Microsoft on this "Declaring an out method is useful when you want a method to return multiple values. A method that uses an out parameter can still a variables as a return type (see return) but it can also return one or more objects to a calling method as out parameters. " But yes, i guess this goes a bit further than what the question is all about.

Comment: My issue was that he won't be able to directly set the `label1.Text` using an out from the method anyways, so why go through all the trouble?

Comment: Yep, in this case this actually seems a training or academic or not so complex, so it would be over-engineering. His question earlier was "how can i get the void function to output text", so i erroneously interpreted that the void was a need. As you said NominSim, you cannot assign the out to label1.Text,and in this case only if there really was a need for the void would it be justifiable. (i'm thinking : have the need to return more than one value, or have a code generator, and not wanting to worry about the class definition)

Comment: Half-broken link: *"Visual Studio 2005 Retired documentation"*

Answer (score 0):

Use a String return type:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = myvoid("foo", true);
}

public string myvoid(string key, bool data)
{
    string a = string.Empty;
    if (data == true)
    {
        a = key + " = true";
        MessageBox.Show(a);
    }
    else
    {
        a = key + " = false";
        MessageBox.Show(a);
    }
    return a;
 }
```

If you wana stick with the void you can do this

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     myvoid("foo", true , label1);
 }

 public void myvoid(string key, bool data, label lb)
 {
     string a = string.Empty;
     if (data == true)
     {
         a = key + " = true";
         MessageBox.Show(a);
     }
     else
     {
         a = key + " = false";
         MessageBox.Show(a);
     }

     lb.Text = a;
 }
```